# c++ json parse to string one line while keepig white spaces

Tags: c++

I have next json

```
{
        "name": "John",
        "age": 30,
        "address": {
            "street": "123 Main St",
            "city": "New York",
            "country": {
                          "street": "123 Main St",
                "city": "New York",
                "country": {
                    "street": "123 Main St",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "country": "USA"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

using cpp json framework, I would like to serialize it to string one line.

most important to keep white spaces (for example "street": "123 Main St" has white spaces before)

I have a code, but it ignores any white spaces

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include "rapidjson/document.h"
    #include "rapidjson/stringbuffer.h"
    #include "rapidjson/writer.h"
    using namespace rapidjson;
    
    int main() {
        // Create the JSON object
        const char* json = R"(
            {
                "name": "John",
                "age": 30,
                "address": {
                    "street": "123 Main St",
                    "city": "New York",
                    "country": {
                        "street": "123 Main St",
                        "city": "New York",
                        "country": {
                            "street": "123 Main St",
                            "city": "New York",
                            "country": "USA"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        )";
    
        Document document;
        document.Parse(json);
    
        StringBuffer buffer;
        Writer<StringBuffer> writer(buffer);
        document.Accept(writer);
        std::cout << buffer.GetString() << std::endl;    

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: So you asking for a JSON library that preserves whitespace in the document when it's not important in the format?

Comment: Is there a call in the API that you are using that formats the JSON with a user-defined number of spaces?  What if you wanted no spaces, so as to compress the JSON as compact as possible?  I would be surprised if no function in the library you're using doesn't exist.

Comment: I have tried use sevreal frameworks, no one of them did not success to keep white spaces

Comment: @drescherjm, format is a json

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking.  The whitespace *between* keys/values/etc. doesn't matter.  Are you looking for a way to serialize an object into indented, human-readable JSON?  Something else?  What *specific* whitespace are you referring to and why specifically does it matter?

Comment: @FelX3 What is the importance of keeping the whitespace?  For readability purposes?  You have another module that requires whitespace?

Comment: The JSON format specifies that the whitespace between keys ... is not important so I would not expect a library to do the extra work to support something that is ignored by the format.

Comment: suppose I have a server, I got json, I got it from server with hash calculated, now someone on client side, added white spaces, so obvious calculated hash will be not the same as came from server. so my goal to preserve the json as is, including white space(does not matter, it can be any change)

Comment: Why not just remove all spaces, then hash?

Comment: The only reliable thing is what was mentioned by @Nathan -- remove all extraneous spaces and then hash that result.  Not only is it reliable, it keeps the actual JSON as compact as possible, considering it is going to and from client to server.

Comment: *so my goal to preserve the json as is* -- Then this to me has nothing to do with JSON in particular.  It has everything to do with any normal text, and see if changes were made by calculating the hash.  Step 1) Calculate hash of the text, regardless of whether it is JSON or not.  Step 2) Confirm that the text is valid JSON.  Is this the goal?

Comment: You could also make a BSON blob out of it and hash that. BSON is great for serializing JSON so you kill two birds with one stone.